# Clicking bar@reputation graph, reputation changes wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

It seems when your clicking the reputation bar for single days, you get the reputation for the previous day. Also the x axis ticks do not seem to be alligned with the tool-tips.

E.g. in the screenshot below:

- The Tooltip says June 6.
- The tick is labelled June 7.
- The list of reputation changes is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: It's quite strange that it's a duplicate but still around at least a year and a half after /.\/.\